# Ruby on Rails: Cucumber: Test that only passes when ran by itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm also using Capybara.
I have a bunch of test cases.. and two of them only pass when I run the tests separate from rake cucumber:all or cucumber features

I have my testing set up so that the DB only clears as one of the above commands starts, rather than finishes, so that I can play with everything after the tests have ran.

What's really weird is that the two tests that only pass when run by themselves are exact copies of tests i have in a different features file.

I'm filling out a form with "When I fill in the following:"
And I have it show me the page after its done with that step. None of the fields are filled in. The only thing I changed, was the data on the right side of the table.. the stuff that is supposed to go into the fields.  Strangely, though, this step passes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very common scenario when you have something cached in your classes (class variables, defined class methods, etc.). There's probably some expectation somewhere that something should not exist, but does (hence not executing some code).

Comment: kinda... I still haven't figured out all the quirks of the capybara and how it interfaces with the product I'm working on.... as it turns out... I just needed the @javascript tag before those tests. I hadn't realized the tests needed javascript.